# Compare with mutiple rows in database

Tags: database, oracle, database-design

I have a table named weight_break for example 0-10, 10-20, 20-30.

I store above values as 3 records in a table WEIGHT_BREAK with column names (PK, FK, FROM_WEIGHT, TO_WEIGHT) stated below.

PK|
FK|
FROM_WEIGHT|
TO_WEIGHT|

100|
T1|
0|
10|

101|
T1|
10|
20|

102|
T1|
20|
30|

Note: All the 3 records are related by FK column as they have same value for all 3 rows.

I want to make sure that user should not insert 0-10, 10-20, 20-30 again basically these 3 records together. How can I do this multiple rows equals check in DB query?

Answer (score 0):

You could make FROM_WEIGHT and TO_WEIGHT unique like so:

```
alter table weight_break 
add constraint unq_weight_class UNIQUE(FK, FROM_WEIGHT, TO_WEIGHT);
```

This way, a user would be able to enter a weight class from, say 0-11 in your above table for the same FK, but would not be able to insert another 0-10.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Either the from_weight or the to_weight is redundant, and you only need one of them to define the bands. You would then need only a unique constraint, and could reconstruct the from/to pair by querying the table easily enough.